# Cannot import modules when running unit tests with catkin_make run_tests in ROS noetic with python3

Tags: ros, python, ros-noetic, unit-testing, setup.py

I am trying to write unit tests for my ROS node in python and cannot import files from my src/ directory even though I believe I have configured everything correctly. I will walk through my problem to provide as much information as possible.

Step 1: Create package:

`catkin_create_pkg test rospy`

`touch test/src/main.py`

`touch test/src/adder.py`

Step 2: Write code:

adder.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

class Adder:

    def add(self, a , b):
        sum = a + b
        return sum
```

main.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
from adder import Adder

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('test_node')

    adder = Adder()
    result = adder.add(1, 2)
    print(result)
    rospy.spin()
```

So far so good. When I chmod +x main.py and catkin_make, I can do rosrun test main.py, and the number 3 is printed to the screen.

The issue occurs when I try to run unit tests. I create the tests as follows:

`mkdir catkin_ws/src/test/unit_tests`

`touch catkin_ws/src/test/unit_tests/adder_test.py`

`touch catkin_ws/src/test/unit_tests/adder_test.test`

adder_test.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
import unittest
from adder import Adder

class AdderTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def testAdd(self):

        adder = Adder()
        result = adder.add(1, 1)
        self.assertEqual(result, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import rosunit
    rospy.init_node('adder_test')
    rosunit.unitrun('unit_test', 'adder_test', AdderTest)
```

adder_test.test:

```
<launch>
    <test test-name="AdderTest" pkg="test" type="adder_test.py"/>
</launch>
```

I add rosunit as a test_depend in package.xml and then attempt:
`catkin_make run_tests`

But I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adder'`

I have done a bit of research into this, and I managed to find what I think is the correct solution, so I perform the following steps:

Create setup.py:
`touch catkin_ws/src/test/setup.py`

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
        packages=['test'],
        package_dir = {'': 'src'},
        )
setup(**setup_args)
```

I then add the following lines to my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
catkin_python_setup()

catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
   src/adder.py
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

My complete CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(test)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
)

## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
catkin_python_setup()

catkin_package(
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

 catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
   src/adder.py
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)


find_package(rostest REQUIRED)
add_rostest(unit_tests/adder_test.test)
```

I also create an empty `__init__.py` file under catkin_ws/src/test/src/

Then I recompile with catkin_make and source again.

However when I try to run `catkin_make run_tests`, I get the same error:

```
from adder import Adder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adder'
```

I can 'fix' this problem by manually appending the path to my test/src directory before importing the module, however this is extremely bad practice and does not make the package portable if this path has to be changed every time.

What am I doing wrong? I have looked as far as I can online and I believe that I am doing everything correctly, but I obviously must not be.

I am using ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04 with python3.8

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by moving adder.py to it's own directory under src named test.

Comment: You mean: `./src/test/adder.py`?